# Measure theory, notation question, a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, notation, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

I have in my notes

$$\|f\|_\infty := \inf\{c\in \mathbb{R} : |f(\omega)|\leq c \quad a.e. \}$$

Can I take that to mean

$$\|f\|_\infty := \inf\{c\in \mathbb{R} : |f(\omega)|\leq c \quad \forall \omega \in A \; st\; \mu(A^c)=0 \}$$

Comment: How do you find your set $A$?

Comment: @AritroPathak The definition of a.e. that I have doesn't really describe an easy way to construct $A$.

Comment: That is incorrect. Take $f (x) = -x$ on $[0,1]$ then $\|f\|_\infty = 1$ but the above has $\sup\{c\in \mathbb{R} : f(\omega)>c \quad a.e. \} = -1$.

Comment: @copper.hat I fixed it. But I'm still puzzled about the definition of almost everywhere. That is what I want to know. Also I'm not even sure, is $\|f\|_\infty$ as defined here, a function or a constant?

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\|f\|_\infty$ is an upper bound and not a function cause otherwise the a.e. condition would not make sense, right?

Comment: @ColdHeartOfStone: Are you asking about how measure zero is defined or how it is used in the context of the essential supremum?

Comment: @copper.hat I am trying to understand how exactly to interpret a.e. but I think I now have the answer. Is it correct to say $\|f\|_\infty = \inf\left\{c \in\mathbb{R} : \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega : |f(w)|>c\}) = 0               \right\}$

Comment: @ColdHeartOfStone: Yes, that is a better definition. Another, equivalent one is $\inf_{g \sim f} \sup_x |g(x)|$. The notation $g \sim f$ means  $g$ is equal to$f$ ae.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your notation is incorrect.  When you write something like $$\forall \omega \in A \; \text{such that}\; \mu(A^c)=0$$ you are quantifying over $\omega$, and the variable $A$ is free.  So this expression only is meaningful if you have already given a definition of $A$, and you are making an assertion about all $\omega$ which are in this $A$ with the property that $\mu(A^c)=0$ (which is a queer thing to say, since the condition $\mu(A^c)=0$ does not involve $\omega$ at all).

Instead you could say something like 
$$\|f\|_\infty := \inf\{c\in \mathbb{R} : \exists A \text{ such that } \mu(A^c)=0 \text{ and } \forall\omega\in A,  |f(\omega)|\leq c \}.$$

More simply, you could also just pick a specific $A$, since if any $A$ works, then $A=\{\omega:|f(\omega)|\leq c\}$ works.  So you could just say $$\|f\|_\infty := \inf\{c\in \mathbb{R} : \mu(\{\omega:|f(\omega)|>c\})=0\}.$$